# retriveing data from one box and one text file

Tags: php

Hello i have a search page which has got a **drop down menu, text field and a submit button**. the drop down menu has three items one is Property ID, Property Deal Type and third one is Property Status.

i want the user select any of these three and enter the text for the selected item from drop down into the text box and press the button and search for it into database , but unfortunately the query that i have created listing all the records.

where is the problem any one please?

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="1330" border="0" align="center" bordercolor="#000000">
  <th colspan="13"><font size="+3">Search Page</font></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="13">
<select name="searchbox" class="dropdown">
<option value="" selected disabled>Search Criteria</option>
<option value="PropertyID">Search By ID</option>
<option value="PropertyDealType">Search By DealType</option>
<option value="PropertyStatus">Search By Status</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="searchtext" class="search">
&nbsp;
<input type="submit" id="Submitbutton" value="Search"><br >

<?php 

require_once('../db.php');
@$searchtext = $_POST['searchtext'];

$query = "SELECT 
     properties.PropertyID,
     properties.PropertyType,
     properties.PropertyDealType,
     properties.PropertyStatus,

     remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeFullName,

     propertyowners.PropertyOwnerName,
     propertydealers.PropertyDealerName

     FROM remoteemployees,
          propertyowners,
          propertydealers,
          properties

     WHERE 

     properties.PropertyOwnerID=propertyowners.PropertyOwnerID

     AND properties.PropertyDealerID=propertydealers.PropertyDealerID

     AND remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail=properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail

     OR   properties.PropertyDealType = '$searchtext'

     OR   properties.PropertyID = '$searchtext'

     OR   properties.PropertyStatus = '$searchtext'";

    $query_run = $connection->query($query);
      if($query_run->num_rows == 0)
  {
      exit();
  } ?>


  </th></tr>
<tr><th>PropertyID</th><th>Property Type</th><th>Property Deal Type</th><th>Property Owner</th><th>Property Dealer</th>
<th>Remote Emp Name</th><th>Property Status</th><th>Active</th><th>Inactive</th>
</tr>
<?php
    if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
    while($row=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

?>

<tr><td><?php echo $row['PropertyID'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['PropertyType'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['PropertyDealType'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['PropertyOwnerName'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['PropertyDealerName'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['RemoteEmployeeFullName'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['PropertyStatus'] ?></td><td><a href="Property active Page execution.php?PropertyID=<?php echo $row['PropertyID']  ?>">Active Property</a></td><td><a href="Property Inactive Page execution.php?PropertyID=<?php echo $row['PropertyID']  ?>">Inactive Property</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you write only related question and remove extra code ... so it will easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT 
         properties.PropertyID,
         properties.PropertyType,
         properties.PropertyDealType,
         properties.PropertyStatus,

         remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeFullName,

         propertyowners.PropertyOwnerName,
         propertydealers.PropertyDealerName

         FROM remoteemployees,
              propertyowners,
              propertydealers,
              properties

         WHERE 

         properties.PropertyOwnerID=propertyowners.PropertyOwnerID

                AND properties.PropertyDealerID=propertydealers.PropertyDealerID

                AND remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail=properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail

                AND   ( properties.PropertyDealType = '$searchtext'

                        OR   properties.PropertyID = '$searchtext'

                        OR   properties.PropertyStatus = '$searchtext'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Modification to your query

```
$query = "SELECT 
     properties.PropertyID,
     properties.PropertyType,
     properties.PropertyDealType,
     properties.PropertyStatus,

     remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeFullName,

     propertyowners.PropertyOwnerName,
     propertydealers.PropertyDealerName

     FROM remoteemployees,
          propertyowners,
          propertydealers,
          properties

     WHERE 

     properties.PropertyOwnerID=propertyowners.PropertyOwnerID

     AND properties.PropertyDealerID=propertydealers.PropertyDealerID

     AND remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail=properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail

     OR   properties.{$_POST['searchbox']} = '$searchtext'";
```

As you will receive field name from dropdown so just use that.
Adittionally you should use table `JOINS` instead of selecting from multiple tables with conditions. Also should use `LIKE` keyword in string comparisons.